# How can i do editable paragraph in ASP.NET

Tags: javascript, css, asp.net, jeditable, paragraph

I am tired by research on my problem but i didn't get any conclusion to satisfy my wanted solution to my prob. Here is my problem:

"I have a paragraph with some blanks in it in my ASP.NET Page. At runtime those blanks will be filled by user. How can i make them(blanks) editable without effect my design (Css). I tried with labels, text boxes to enter user info. Every time i loose my blanks, alignment. So please help me any one. I will be thankful to them."

Comment: You need to post your code to get help with what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: add some tags like spans and set the attribute 'contenteditable' to true  i guess

Comment: set the 'contenteditable' property of the paragraph to 'true'. try reading this http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_contenteditable.asp

Comment: Thanks for answers. All helpful.